# PayPal Express Checkout - how to properly capture shipping address (for shipping costs calculations)?

Tags: paypal, workflow, express-checkout

I need to capture buyer's shipping address BEFORE going to paypal express checkout so I can properly estimate shipping costs. As far as I understand, I need to use "Payment Flow" option of express checkout - pls go to https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/intro.php and click on "Payment Flow" tab to see it.

Question is: if I have "Checkout with PayPal" button on the shopping cart screen (first one) and user clicks it - then user will NOT be redirected to PayPal page but instead will go to "Enter your shipping address" page on my website. And only after that user will redirected to the PayPal page. I think it's confusing and probably violation of PayPal rules. Am I right? How the correct workflow should look like in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer - in order to provide shipping costs options based on user's shipping address, [Instant Update API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECInstantUpdateAPI) should be used. That will be a webservice call on your server from PayPal with buyer's selected address.